# Is it possible to change the behaviour/style of the "notification-area"-envelope-icon in GNOME Flashback?

Tags: gnome, icons, notification, gnome-flashback

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. I'm using GNOME Flashback and I'm not entirely satisfied how the notification-area currently works/looks, specifically with notifications for new messages from [Signal-Desktop](https://signal.org/) (Messenger application).

[image: New Message indication]

The notification icon for new messages is very small and quite inconspicuous, so I regularly don't notice it and thus miss new messages.

Is it possible to configure this? Can I maybe simply replace the image that is used? Where is it in the filesystem? Is it possible to animate the icon?

If none of that is possible, is it possible to disable usage of the notification-area for the Signal-Desktop-Application and restore the old behaviour (Focus the app's window on new messages)? There is a list of applications in the settings-dialog for "Notifications", but it is not in this list. I'd prefer that if the notification-icon can't be changed to something more flashy.

Comment: As you like old GNOME, I can recommend a better method - switching to [MATE DE] (http://mate-desktop.org/). You can try it in VM to test notifications and other things, then install to the system with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop`. Modern trends of GNOME do not get guarantee that they will save FlashBack session in familiar way.

Comment: @N0rbert I'm using gnome-flashback in conjunction with Xmonad and it was sometimes painful to get it all play nice with each other, so I'm not very eager to tinke with my desktop again. But I will give it a shot in the future when I have to spend some time to reconfigure my Desktop (Xmonad won't work on Wayland and I have to move to i3/awesome). Thanks for the hint/reminder though!

Comment: @N0rbert How switching to MATE would solve his problem? Christian, it is not configurable! I would suggest to open bug [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-flashback/issues).